# jQuery to Native JavaScript (simple click call function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert the following jQuery to native JavaScript, but can't seem to get it to work.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var genHash = "";
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
      genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }

    $("input").val(genHash);
  }).click();
});
```

**Native JavaScript**:

```
function PasswordGenerator() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var genHash = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
    genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("input").value = genHash;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick = function() {
  PasswordGenerator();
};
PasswordGenerator();
```

```js
function PasswordGenerator() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var genHash = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
    genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("input").value = genHash;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick = function() {
  PasswordGenerator();
};
PasswordGenerator();
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>
  Generate Password
</button>
```

Comment: I am curious as why you do not wish to use JQuery

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList (/HTMLCollection), you have to access elements in the list by index, before you can access their properties.

Comment: I love JQuery I just wanted to try native roots once again. Mostly cause I'm bored.

Comment: oh ok thanks #CBroe, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `index` `[0]` of element within `HTMLCollection` returned by [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName)

```js
function PasswordGenerator() {
  var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var genHash = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
    genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }
  // add index `[0]` of element within `HTMLCollection` after call to
  // `.getElementsByTagName("input")`
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = genHash;
}
// add index `[0]` of element within `HTMLCollection` after call to
// `.getElementsByTagName("button")`
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  PasswordGenerator();
});
// call `click` event on `button`
button.click();
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>
  Generate Password
</button>
```

Comment: I forgot about how native javascript loops through arrays. So `[0]` selects the first (in this case only element of that tag) and works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why we use jQuery. Things that seem completely normal aren't as straight forward in plain vanilla JS. You can't, for example, apply event handlers, or set the value of, the results of a `getElementsByTagName(...)` call. This is because it returns a plain array, where jQuery returns an object that has all of this figured out (it loops through the array and applies your actions to each element).

```js
function PasswordGenerator() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var genHash = "";
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
        genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
        inputs[z].value = genHash;
    }
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var z = 0; z < buttons.length; z++) {
    buttons[z].addEventListener("click", function () {
        PasswordGenerator();
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>
  Generate Password
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below, it is pretty much the same what you did but with some correction and comments about how it should behave.

```js
function PasswordGenerator() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var genHash = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);
    genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = genHash;
  //In this case you need to select the first element in the array (document.getElementsByTagName return an array of elements matching the tag name.
  //In the case you had more than one element, you would need to iterate it since jQuery will do it by default if you have $("input").va("xxx"). It will assign the values to all the elements "input"
}

//Way 1 - The same as above. You need to select the first element of the array because in this case, you only have a button.
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  PasswordGenerator();
});

//Way 2 - By definition, querySelector will retrieve the first matching element. In this case, it will retrieve your button
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //PasswordGenerator();
  alert("Called");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>
  Generate Password
</button>
```